# How to commit a docker image to another hub directory?

Tags: docker

I have a docker hub with a private and a public space.

I would like to commit a modified version of the public image to the private one.

How can I do that?

> $ docker ps
>   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND      CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
>   488cbc12c206        archstrike-with-readme   "bash"              9
>   seconds ago       Up 7 sec

Hub address: https://hub.docker.com/u/aurelien2a/

push from archstricke (public) to a private one

Comment: Could you provide me some more information. have you tried anything so far.

Comment: added the running one and hub address. Is that enough? @Mongrel

Answer (score 1):

on Docker Hub, you can have public or private repositories. You have to tag your image with the URL of one of your private repo, and then push it.
If priv is your private repository:

- docker tag 488cbc12c206 aurelien2a/priv/myimage:1.0
- docker push aurelien2a/priv/myimage:1.0

or something similar

Comment: that does not works: docker push hub.docker.com/u/aurelien2a/private/blackarch:1.0
The push refers to a repository [hub.docker.com/u/aurelien2a/private/blackarch]
14b4657a4156: Preparing 
f657b85d5601: Preparing 
Index response didn't contain any endpoints

Comment: sorry, I made a typo in the repo name in the second command

Comment: hum ... got the same .. or I do not see the point: $ docker tag 2ec1aee68d12 hub.docker.com/u/aurelien2a/priv/blackarch:1.0
aurelien@icesheet:~$ docker push hub.docker.com/u/aurelien2a/priv/blackarch:1.0
The push refers to a repository [hub.docker.com/u/aurelien2a/priv/blackarch]
14b4657a4156: Preparing 
f657b85d5601: Preparing 
Index response didn't contain any endpoints

Comment: got it! just reduce to the correct place without the docker.io

Comment: docker push aurelien2a/blackarch:latest
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/aurelien2a/blackarch]
14b4657a4156: Pushing 121.4 MB/671.9 MB
f657b85d5601: Mounted from aurelien2a/archstrike

Comment: Correct your response, i'll give you the point ;-)

Comment: strange, we are using internally a private docker repository, and we have to fully qualify the URL of the repo, I'll have to look up this in the documentation

Comment: maybe because you use a docker registry  @Jean-Pasal J.

Comment: And to works it need a commit. `docker commit <container ID> <repository>:<tag>` then `docker push <short repository name>:<tag>`

Comment: docker commit is only if you want to transform a container into an image.

Comment: That is the case, to keep part of the evolution.